# Display Hex in PuTTY for Serial

Tags: putty, serial-port, serial

Does anyone know if there is a way to get PuTTY to show the hex values of what it's receiving over a serial connection instead of characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In initial screen

Session | Logging

Select All session output, then select save file.

After saving the file, use any hex editor to see the result.

Comment: This also helped for me when Putty was not showing anything at all on the screen because of blank values (i.e. 0x01 which is "start of heading" in ascii. )

Comment: All 0x00 were missing for me (Putty 0.67 on Win10, visualized with fhred 1.7.1)

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the `raw` protocol on the session screen in the configuration. It will show whatever is being transmitted directly from where you're connecting. If the device/system you're connecting to isn't transmitting HEX codes though, you may need a specialized terminal program to translate the output to hex codes.

Comment: The question is tagged and specifically mentions serial port communication.

Comment: In raw mode, it still doesn’t print non-printing characters. It also seems not to put them in clipboard when copying/pasting.